# Focus field when removing part of form dynamically in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a form which is created dynamically where a user can register multiple users at once and by default it displays standard fields such as Name, phone number, etc..

They user has the option to add another user which in turns another creates another set of fields with the same fields and so forth.

Whenever I add a new user and the new set of fields are created, I automatically set the focus on the Name field which is the first field using the following:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputName = React.createRef();
}

render() {
...
return (
    <div className="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id={"inputName_" + contactForm.index}
          placeholder="Name"
          autoFocus={true}
          ref={this.inputName}
        />
      </div>
    }
  ...
}
```

This seems to work because of the 'autoFocus' rather than the reference as I'm not actually using it (researching something else) but my question is, when I remove a set of fields, how do I restore the focus to the previous Name field. For example:

If I delete the form for the second user, how do I restore the focus on the Name field of the first user

Or

if I delete the third user, how can I restored the focus on the Name of the second user

and so forth??

Even if I use the reference, from what I understand, this gets destroyed on dismount but I guess when I mount a new section of my form, it should have a reference to field Name of the previous section?

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
// focus the Name field once the component
// is build
componentDidMount() {
   if (this.inputName) {
      this.inputName.current.focus();
   }
}

// restore the focus to the Name field
// when the sub form component is deleted 
// and the form gets re-drawn.

componentDidUpdate() {
   if (this.inputName) {
      this.inputName.current.focus();
   }
}
```

**Update 1:**

Some refactoring and scroll into view if that of any use to you:

```
componentDidMount() {
   focusInputName();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
   focusInputName();
}

focusInputName() {
    const { index } = this.props;

    if (this.inputName) {
        if (index > 0) {
            this.inputName.current.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "smooth"
            });
        }
        this.inputName.current.focus();
    }
}
```

In my case, I only want to scroll into view when I'm on the second, third or forth sub-form (set of fields) where the `index` represent my sub-form index which is incremented/decreased as I add/delete a sub-form component to my form component.

Hope this helps others!